# How to find all id's to an array from array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find all id's to an array from array of objects. Here through normal for loop I can able to get but using ECMA new features by findAll etc..how to get?

```js
let items = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie", isSelected: false},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10752, name: "War", isSelected: false},
      {id: 37, name: "Western", isSelected: true}
    ]
```

Here I want to find all id's based on isSelected is true.

Comment: Use `.filter()`, so something like `items.filter(({isSelected}) => isSelected);` should give you what you're after if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filter and map

```js
let items = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie", isSelected: false},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10752, name: "War", isSelected: false},
      {id: 37, name: "Western", isSelected: true}
    ]
    console.log(items.filter(function(e){return e.isSelected}).map(function(e){
    return e.id
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let items = [
  { id: 28, name: "Action", isSelected: true },
  { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie", isSelected: false },
  { id: 53, name: "Thriller", isSelected: true },
  { id: 10752, name: "War", isSelected: false },
  { id: 37, name: "Western", isSelected: true }
]
let res = items.filter(({ isSelected }) => isSelected).map(({id}) => id);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple map function will do your job

```
let items = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie", isSelected: false},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10752, name: "War", isSelected: false},
      {id: 37, name: "Western", isSelected: true}
]

items.map(item => console.log(item.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter the array to get the objects with `isSelected` as `true` then use `map()` to get the `id` of those objects:

```js
let items = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie", isSelected: false},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller", isSelected: true},
      {id: 10752, name: "War", isSelected: false},
      {id: 37, name: "Western", isSelected: true}
];
let res = items.filter(({isSelected}) => isSelected).map(({id}) => id);
console.log(res);
```